# Property: text-decoration-skip-ink does not exist: none

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I check my website with the W3C CSS Validator I get this errors:

Property text-decoration-skip-ink does not exist: none.
Property backdrop-filter does not exist: blur(10px).
I heard that this is an error from W3C.

Does this affect my website in the future? If so, How can I solve the errors?

This is my whole css:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'montserrat';
    src: url(../fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}
@font-face{
    font-family: 'playfair';
    src: url(../fonts/PlayfairDisplay-Medium.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
}



*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
}
body{
    background-color: white;
}


/* LOADER */ 

.preload{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    z-index:9999;
}



  .loader {
    border: 5px solid #ffffff;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }

.preload-finish{
    opacity:0;
    pointer-events: none;
}








/* BANNER & NAV */

.banner{
    margin:0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size:cover;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.9),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(../img/pozabackground-home2.jpg);    
    background-position: center;
    box-shadow:1px 2px 4px 0px #00000075 !important;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}



.navigatie{
    background-color:transparent;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}


.logo {
    float: left;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.navbar-brand{
    color:white !important;
}
.navbar-brand img{
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    margin:-32px 0px -25px 0px;
}

nav ul {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top:5px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

nav ul li:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 48px;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 24px;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1.1px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}


/* FUNDAL JS */


.fundal{
    background:#104f47 !important;
    box-shadow:1px 2px 4px 0px #00000075 !important;
}

.fundal .nav-btn {
    background-color:#104f47;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow:1px 2px 4px 0px #00000075;
}

.fundal .nav-btn i{
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
}




#nav:checked + .nav-btn {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: #104f47;
}

#nav:checked + .nav-btn i {
    background: #fff;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

#nav:checked + .nav-btn i:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(6px) rotate(180deg);
}

#nav:checked + .nav-btn i:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}

#nav:checked + .nav-btn i:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(90deg);
}

#nav:checked ~ .nav-wrapper {
    z-index: 9990;
    display:block
}

#nav:checked ~ .nav-wrapper ul li a {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}



/* MEDIA SCREEN NAVBAR PTR TLF */

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){

    .navigatie{
        background-color:transparent;
        width:100%;
        position: absolute;;
        z-index: 99;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
        


    .navbar-brand img{
        height:100px;
        margin:-20px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    .nav-wrapper {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
        background: #fff;
        display:none;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }

    .nav-wrapper ul {
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translateY(-50%);
          width: 100%;
    }

    .nav-wrapper ul li {
          display: block;
          float: none;
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          padding-top:10px;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
    }



    .nav-wrapper ul li:not(:first-child) {
          margin-left: 0;
    }

    .nav-wrapper ul li a {
          padding: 10px 24px;
          opacity: 0;
          color: #000;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: 600;
          letter-spacing: 1.2px;
          transform: translateX(-20px);
          transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }

    .nav-btn {
          position: fixed;
          right: 30px;
          top: 28px;
          display: block;
          width: 47px;
          height: 46px;
          cursor: pointer;
          z-index: 9999;
          border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .nav-btn i {
          display: block;
          width: 20px;
          height: 2px;
          background: #fff;
          border-radius: 2px;
          margin-left: 14px;
    }

    .nav-btn i:nth-child(1) {
          margin-top: 16px;
    }

    .nav-btn i:nth-child(2) {
          margin-top: 4px;
          opacity: 1;
    }

    .nav-btn i:nth-child(3) {
          margin-top: 4px;
    }
}


/* SCRIS DE LA BANNER */

.title{
    position: absolute;
    top:47%;
    left:35%;
    text-align: left;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.title h1{
    color:#fff;
    font-family: playfair;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#f5f6f8;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    letter-spacing:3px;
}



.title .button a{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding:13px 20px;
    border:none;
    color:white;
    font-family: montserrat;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    background-color:#104f47;
    box-shadow:1px 2px 4px 0px #00000075;
    outline:none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
}
.title .button a:hover{
    background-color:#104f47;
    color:white;
}



/* DESPRE NOI */

.About-head-section{
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}

.servicii{
    padding-top:130px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.About-head-section .servicii h1{
    margin-top: -45px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: montserrat;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color:#072523;
}


.About-head-section .servicii h1::after{
    content:'';
    background:#148071;
    display:block;
    width: 320px;
    height: 3px;
    margin:10px auto;
    margin-left:-50px;
}
.servicii p{
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
.buton-despre{
    text-align: center;
}
.buton-despre a{
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid rgb(87, 87, 87);
    color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
    padding:10px 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: montserrat;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:12px;
    outline:none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.buton-despre a:hover{
    background-color:rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.678);
}
.servicii img{
    margin-top:20px;
    width: 420px;
}





/* DE CE NOI */
.curved{
    margin:0px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    clip-path:polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 85%);
    background:#b1b1b12c;
}


.details{
    text-align:center;
    color:rgb(24, 24, 24);
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:110px;
}
.details .row{
    margin-right:-50px;
}
.details .container {
    padding:0px;
}
.details h1{
    margin:0px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: montserrat;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    color:#072523;
}

.details h1::after{
    content:'';
    background:#148071;
    display:block;
    width: 875px;
    height: 3px;
    margin:10px auto;
    margin-left:-50px;
}


.details .interior{
    text-align: left;
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}


.details .number span{
    color:#072523;
    font-size:35px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.details .number h2{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family: montserrat;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#072523;
}
.details p{
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: montserrat;
}
.details .coloana-scris{
    padding-top:10px !important;
    padding-left:30px;

}
.details .coloana-poza{
    padding-top:35px;
}
.details .coloana-poza img{  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #bbbbbb;
}






/* SERVICII */

/* SERVICII */

/* features design */
/* boxes */
.explore-section{
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 10px 80px 10px;
    padding-bottom:30px;

}
.explore-section .container{
    /* flexbox style */
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow:wrap;
    width: 100%;
    
}
.explore-section .container .box{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:20px;
    width: 320px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px #bbbbbb;
}


.explore-section .titlu h1{
    padding-top:50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: montserrat;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom:60px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#072523;
}
.explore-section .titlu h1:after{
    content:'';
    background:#148071;
    display:block;
    width: 720px;
    height: 3px;
    margin:10px auto;
}

.explore-section .container .box .scris{
    padding:20px 20px 20px 10px;
}
.poza-servicii{ 
    width: 100%;
}
.poza-servicii:hover{
    opacity:0.8;
}

.poza-servicii h2{
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: montserrat;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin:10px;
}
.poza-servicii a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.buton-servicii{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}
.buton-servicii a{
    background-color: #104f47;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding:10px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:12px;
    outline:none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.buton-servicii::before{
    content:'';
    background:#104f47;
    display:block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    margin:30px auto;
}

.buton-servicii a:hover{
    background-color: #148071;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1200px){
    .box{
        width:20%;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:600px){
        .box{
            width:65%;
        }
}
}



/* TESTIMONIALS */
.testimonials{
    background:#b1b1b12c;
    padding-bottom:110px;
    clip-path:polygon(0 0, 100% 15%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
.testimonials-title h1{
    padding-top:130px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: montserrat;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    color:#072523;
}
.testimonials .container{
    margin:0 auto;
}

.testimonials .interior{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0.5px #bbbbbb;
    padding:40px;
    background:white;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.testimonials .container .interior:hover{
    background:#104f47;

}
.testimonials .interior p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    transition:0.5s;
    font-family: montserrat;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.testimonials .interior h2{
    margin:20px 0 0;
    padding:0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#104f47;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.testimonials .container .interior h2 span{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#afb8b7;
    transition:0.5s;
}

.testimonials .container .interior:hover p,
.testimonials .container .interior:hover h2,
.testimonials .container .interior:hover h2 span,
.testimonials .container .interior:hover i{
    color:#fff;
}

.testimonials .coloana i{
    padding-bottom:15px;
    font-size:40px;
    transition:0.5s;
}




/* BACK TO TOP BUTTON */


#TopBtn {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 99;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #8dadac;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  #TopBtn:hover {
    opacity:0.8;
  }










/* ------------------------------------------TELEFON - 991 ------------------------- */



/* MEDIA */
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
    

    .banner{
        background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.9),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(../img/pozabackground-home2-991px.jpg);
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }

    .title .button a{
        padding: 10px 16px;
    }



    /* DESPRE NOI */

    .button button{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .buton-despre{
        text-align: center;
    }

    .servicii{
        padding-top:100px;
        padding-bottom:30px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .servicii .poza img{
        width: 430px;
        padding-top:50px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }
    .servicii p{
        padding-bottom:20px;
    }

    /* DE CE NOI */

    .curved{
        clip-path:polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 95%);
        padding-bottom:20px;
    }
    
    .details{
        padding-top:30px;
        padding-bottom:40px;
    }

    .details h1::after{
        content:'';
        background:#148071;
        display:block;
        width: 500px;
        height: 3px;
        margin:10px auto;
        margin-left:-50px;
    }

    .details .number h2{
        font-size:18px;
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 10px;
        color:#148071;
    }
    


    .details .coloana-poza{
        display:none;
    }



    /* SERVICII */
    .explore-section .titlu h1:after{
        width: 150px;
        height: 3px;
        margin:10px auto;
    }
    .explore-section{
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 10px 80px 10px;
    padding-bottom:30px;

    }
    .explore-section .container{
        /* flexbox style */
        border-radius: 15px;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
        flex-flow:wrap;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .explore-section .container .box{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin:20px;
        width: 300px;
        border-radius:30px;
    }

    /* TESTIMONIALS */
    .testimonials{
        padding-bottom:80px;
        clip-path:polygon(0 0, 100% 5%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    }

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){
        /* DE CE NOI? */
        .details .number i{
            font-size:20px;
            padding-right:5px;
        }
        .details .number h2{
            font-size:14px;
            padding-bottom:10px;
        }
}



/* 700 ------------------------------------------------------------------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){

    .title{
        top:45%;
        left:50%;
        margin-right: -100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .title h1{
        padding-top:50px;
        font-size:30px;
    }
    .title .button a{
        font-size: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        padding:13px 20px;
        margin-top:0px;
        color:#fff;
    }

}




/* 600 ------------------------------------------------------------------- */





@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .navbar-brand img{
        height:100px;
        margin:-20px 0px 0px -20px;
    }

    
    .banner{
        background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(../img/pozabackground-home2-mobil.jpg);
    }


    .title h1{
        font-size:30px;
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing:2px;
    }

    .title .button a{
        text-align: center;
        padding:13px 20px;
        margin-top:0px;
        color:#fff;
        font-size:13px
    }
    

    /* DESPRE NOI*/

    .About-head-section{
        padding-top:20px;
        padding-bottom:30px;
    }
    .servicii{
        padding-top:20px;
    }
    .About-head-section .servicii h1{
        padding-top: 60px;
        font-size: 23px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .About-head-section .servicii h1::after{
        width: 150px;
        height: 3px;
        margin:10px auto;
        margin-left:-50px;
    }
    
    .buton-despre{
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom:0px;
    }
    .servicii .poza img{
        width: 320px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }
    

    /* DE CE NOI */
    .curved{
        margin:0px;
        padding-top:30px;
    }


    .details{
        padding-top:20px;
        padding-bottom:50px;
        padding-left:20px;
    }
    .details .row {
        margin-right: -20px;
    }
    .details  h1{
        margin:0px 0px 0px 12px;
        font-size: 23px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .details h1::after{
        width: 150px;
        height: 3px;
        margin:10px auto;
        margin-left:-50px;
    }


    .details .interior{
        margin-bottom:25px;
        text-align: left;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    .details .number i{
        font-size:30px;
        padding-right:0px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .details .number h2{
        font-size:18px;
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
    .details p{
        padding-top:0px;
        padding-left:0px;
        font-size:15px;
        padding-bottom:15px;
    }

    .details .coloana-scris {
        padding-top: 10px !important;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }



    /* SERVICII */

    .explore-section{
        padding:0px 15px 50px 15px;
    }
    .explore-section .titlu h1{
        margin-top:0px;
        font-size:23px;
        padding-bottom:5px;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .explore-section .titlu h1:after{
        width: 150px;
        height: 3px;
        margin:10px auto;
        margin-left:-50px;
    }
    .explore-section .container .box{
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin:20px 0px 20px 0px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .poza-servicii h2{
        padding:10px 5px 0 5px;
    }
    

    /* TESTIMONIALS */

    .testimonials h1{
        padding-top:100px;
        font-size:23px;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left:30px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .testimonials h1::after{
        content:'';
        background:#148071;
        display:block;
        width: 150px;
        height: 3px;
        margin:10px auto;
        margin-left:-50px;
    }
    .testimonials .interior {
        padding: 20px;
    }


    /* BACK TO TOP BUTTON */


    #TopBtn {
        font-size: 15px;
        width: 47px;
        height: 47px;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }
  


}




/* 450-----------------------------*/




@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {


    .title .button a{
        text-align: center;
        border:none;
        color:#fff;
        font-size:12px;
        padding:12px 17px;
    }

    .banner{
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }


    /* DESPRE NOI */


    .servicii .poza img{
        width: 240px;
    }


}




/* 300-----------------------------*/



@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {


    .navbar-brand img{
        height:100px;
        margin:-20px 0px 0px -20px;
    }
    
    .title h1{
        font-size:23px;
    }
    
    .title .button a{
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 13px;
        margin-top:6px;
        border:none;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: 0.6s ease;
        font-size:12px;
    }

    .interior h2{
        font-size:13px;
    }

    .banner{
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }


    /* DE CE NOI */
    .details .row {
        margin-right: -20px;
    }
  
}





/* INCLUDE LA FOOTER SI CONTACT */

    /* PARTEA DE CONTACT */

    .background-contact{
        background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.9),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(../img/background-contact-3-fullscreen.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
    }
    
    .mesaj{
        padding-top:80px;
        padding-bottom:50px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .mesaj h1{
        color:#fff;
        font-family: montserrat;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color:#fff;
    }
    
    
    .buton-contact{
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom:45px;
    }

    .buton-contact a{
        border: none;
        padding:12px 30px;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: 0.6s ease;
        background-color:#104f47;
        box-shadow:1px 2px 4px 0px #00000075;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .buton-contact a:hover{
        background-color:#104f47;
        color:white;
        border:none;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    
    
    
    
    /* FOOTER */
    
    .page-footer{
        background-color: #222 !important;
        color:white !important;
        margin-top:-50px !important;
    }

    .page-footer .social-media{
        padding-top:20px !important;
    }

    .page-footer .container{
        padding-top:50px;
    }

    .page-footer ul li a{
        text-decoration: none !important;
        color:#fff !important;
        font-size:14px;
    }

    .page-footer ul li a:hover{
        text-decoration: none !important;
        color:#104f47 !important;
    }

    .social-media a i{
        padding-top:10px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 45px;
        background-color: #333;
        border-radius:50%;
    }
    
    .social-media a i:hover{
        color:#104f47 !important;
    }

    .social-media{
        margin-top:-20px;
        padding-bottom:20px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .footer-copyright{
        background-color:#333;
    }

    .footer-copyright p{
        margin-bottom:-5px;
        font-size:13px;
    }
    
    .text-contact::after{
        content:'';
        background:#148071;
        display:block;
        width: 75px; 
        height: 2px;
        margin-top:7px;
    }
    
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    
    
    /* CONTACT */
    
            
    .mesaj h1{
        font-family: montserrat;
        font-size: 23px;
    }
    
    .background-contact{
        background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.9),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(../img/background-contact-3.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    
    .text-contact::after {
        content: '';
        background: #148071;
        display: block;
        width: 75px;
        height: 2px;
        margin: 10px auto;
    }
        
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width:400){
    
        body{
            font-size:13px;
        }
        .banner-contact{
            background-attachment: scroll;
        }  
    
    }
    
    
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    
    
        body{
            font-size:13px;
        }
        .banner-contact{
            background-attachment: scroll;
        }
        
        .mesaj h1{
            font-family: montserrat;
            font-size: 19px;
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It seems text-decoration-skip-ink is in working draft phase.**
Check this
[mdn-documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip)
which also indicates lack of cross-browser support at this point.
This is a just warning. So just ignore it.
We hope that in the future this property will work in all browsers.